# Why isn't my JS working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

So I have this piece of HTML which represents the menu itself:

```
<div id="menu">
                <ul class="pnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About GM</a>
                        <ul class="cnav">
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tournaments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I also have this piece of CSS for this menu:

```
ul.pnav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;    
    margin: 0;
    width: 920px;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: url(topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;
}
ul.pnav li {
    display:inline;
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul.pnav li a{
    padding: 10px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.pnav li a:hover{
    background: url(topnav_hover.gif) no-repeat center top;
}

ul.pnav li ul.cnav {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/
    left: 0; top: 35px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    display: none;
    width: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}
ul.pnav li ul.cnav li{
    display:block;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #252525;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    clear: both;
    width: 170px;
}
```

And I have this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //$("ul.cnav").parent().append("<span></span>");

    $("ul.pnav li").click(function() {

        $(this).parent().find("ul.cnav").slideDown('fast').show();

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){  
            $(this).parent().find("ul.cnav").slideUp('slow');
        });

    });

});
```

which I didn't quite wrote myself,only customized it and which is called like this in the HEAD HTML tag :

```
<script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
```

but the dropdown isn't working,can any1 help me and explain some solution to me?:D

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: I just made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fnkr/Jcuab/

Comment: Isn't working *how*? Have you checked for an error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you've simply forgotten to load jQuery.

Also, I made 1 slight change to your script to make the menu only open its child subnav.

This:

```
$("ul.pnav li").click(function() {
```

Became:

```
$("ul.pnav li a").click(function() {
```

As it seemed to fit better with the line below it.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/DnGRm/

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

before the above  - Tag in case you missed to include jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

before including any js file you should include 'jquery.js' file which you can download form here http://jquery.com/download/